# How to Use Super Dev Mode for Maven based GWT Application

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have multiple Maven Based GWT Project which are using Classic Dev Mode earlier now i am upgrading the GWT version to 2.7 which will not support classic DevMode and i am updating it to use Super dev mode.I want the changes done in the dev mode should reflect in the reload page without compiling the application.how it possible to reflect the changes made in development mode by reloading the page?Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT 2.7 now uses SuperDevMode by default when launching the `DevMode` entry-point (`mvn gwt:run` with Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT), so if it worked before, it should work now; the only difference being how you debug your code (you no longer use `mvn gwt:debug`, you just open the dev tools i your browser when using `mvn gwt:run`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply, can you please tell me where to add this mvn gwt:run command?

Comment: Huh? OK, so maybe first tell us how you "are using Classic Dev Mode" with your current "Maven Based GWT Projects"? Anyway, my point was that you shouldn't have to change anything to your workflow.

Comment: 1.Open Debugger Configuration->Under Java Application->Create New 2.select project and added com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer in main class 3.Argument tab added src src/main module name ,VM Argument 4.added the dependency project and codeserver jar

Comment: @mohammedsameen That is running the Classic Dev Mode using Eclipse, not Maven :)

Comment: @mohammedsameen Actually, that's trying to run SDM through CodeServer; I repeat: with GWT 2.7, you don't have to change anything, just continue launching DevMode with the same arguments as before.